# site reports issue in multibranch pipeline job for spring boot application

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, maven, jenkins

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site) on project test: SiteToolException: The site descriptor cannot be resolved from the repository:

Jenkins job is failing in site reports stage , even though there is a maven site plugin configuration is there pom.xml and in jfrog the location of maven site plugin is there in plugins release , but it is not searching and throwing not found
```

Pom.xml

```
        </plugin>-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

settings.xml

```
         <profile>
        <id>springboot</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>libs-release</name>
                <url>https://tentjnks01.aaa-bcg.net:8543/artifactory/libs-release</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                <url>https://tentjnks01.aaa-bcg.net:8543/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>plugin-central</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>https://tentjnks01.aaa-bcg.net:8543/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>plugin-snapshots</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>https://tentjnks01.aaa- 
                         bcg.net:8543/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>springboot</activeProfile>
```

command executing in jenkins

- export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
- MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
- mvn -P springboot -fae site-deploy -Dmaven.main.skip=true -Dbuild.number=15 -Dgit.branch=ft-kalakala -Dartifact_server_id=JFROG -Dsite_report_url=dav:https://nexus.prd.itmgt.aws.aaa-acg.net/repository/maven-site/HiMarley/ft-kalakala/15-4316d8d1/ -Drevision=ft-kalakala-15-4316d8d1-SNAPSHOT -Dartifact_release_url=https://art-stg.aaa-acg.net:8543/art/libs-release-local -Dartifact_snapshot_url=https://art-stg.aaa-acg.net:8543/art/libs-snapshot-local